# Layout/Template for meteors hot code push

Tags: android, ios, meteor

I´m using a loading template to subscribe my client in all needed collections. When I change some stuff there is a HCP to the client that results in a refresh of the page (white blank screen for some ms).

I have 2 questions.

1. Is it possible to create a template and show it to the client when there is a HCP to avoid the blank screen?
2. Is it possible to do a HCP only when the app is running in the background on iOS and Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to avoid the white screen when hot code push is happening. On mobile, you can use the `mdg:reload-on-resume` package (https://github.com/meteor/mobile-packages/tree/master/packages/mdg:reload-on-resume) to only let hot code push happen right when the app is opened. Unfortunately this is still not in the background, but it's as close as you can get right now.